# GLFW wont initialize my window

Tags: c++, window, game-engine, glfw

I'm trying to follow along on a game engine tutorial,and when the video runs this code, it opens a window. When I do it, it gives the error message that i have in case the window is not created.

```
 #include "window.h"

namespace sparky {

namespace graphics {

    Window::Window(const char *title, int width, int height) {
        m_Title = title;
        m_Width = width;
        m_Height = height;
        if (!init())
            glfwTerminate();
    }

    Window::~Window()
    {
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    bool Window::init()
    {
        if (!glfwInit) {
            std::cout << "Failed To Initialize" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        m_Window = glfwCreateWindow(m_Width, m_Height, m_Title, NULL, NULL);

        if (!m_Window)
        {
            std::cout << "Window Not Created" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_Window);
        return true;

    }

    bool Window::closed() const
    {
        return glfwWindowShouldClose(m_Window);
    }

    void Window::update() const
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(m_Window);
    }

}

}
```

This is my code in window.cpp, i get the window not created error line, here is my window.h

```
#pragma once
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace sparky {

namespace graphics {

    class Window {
    private:
        const char* m_Title;
        int m_Width, m_Height;
        GLFWwindow *m_Window;
        bool m_Closed;
    public:
        Window(const char* title, int width, int height);
        ~Window();
        bool closed() const;
        void update() const;
    private:
        bool init();


    };

}

}
```

and my main class

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "src/graphics/window.h"

int main() {

using namespace sparky;
using namespace graphics;

Window window("Sparks Fly", 800, 600);

while (!window.closed()) {
    window.update();
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
        if (!glfwInit) {
```

Because `glfwInit` is a library function, it will (assuming you've linked properly) always have a valid address that isn't `nullptr`. So the `!glfwInit` changes it to `false`, and goes through the if statement with a care in the world.

This can be fixed by simply *calling* the function, not converting it to a boolean value:

```
        if(!glfwInit()) {
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much, I was trying to fix this for soo long!

Comment: No problemo! :D